# Reducing arrowhead size in HighlightGraph network

Tags: graphs-and-networks, arrowhead

I have a two-dimensional dataset of company names and the type of business they do (retail, tech, food, etc.)

When I do a HighlightGraph, the arrows are huge. Changing ImageSize has no effect.  I have tried the Arrowhead option with no success.

```
      edges = Import[
  "http://chemistry.ncssm.edu/digihum/data/USCompaniesByType.csv"];edgeList = Table[
       edges[[row, 1]] -> edges[[row, 2]],
       {row, 1, Length[edges]}];
      vertList = VertexList[edgeList];
        dc = DegreeCentrality[edgeList];
        dc = N[Rescale[dc]];
     assigndc = Thread[vertList -> dc];
    g1 = HighlightGraph[edgeList, vertList,
       VertexSize -> assigndc,
       ImageSize -> Large,
       AspectRatio -> 1.25, 
       GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding",
       PlotLabel -> 
        "Top Companies \n Degree Centrality Network"];
    SetProperty[g1, {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
      VertexLabelStyle -> 10}]
```

Comment: Could you please make the code functional first? The variables `edgeList`, `vertList`, and `assigndc` are missing from the code.

Comment: edges is still missing...

Comment: try `SetProperty[g1, {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexLabelStyle -> 10, EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[Small]}]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
g1 = HighlightGraph[edgeList, 
   Property[#, VertexSize -> #2] & @@@ assigndc, 
   ImageSize -> Large, 
   AspectRatio -> 1.25, GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding", 
   PlotLabel -> "Top Companies \n Degree Centrality Network"];

SetProperty[g1, {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexLabelStyle -> 10, EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[Small]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks!   I had that in a list of options for EdgeStyle, but must have mis-coded it.